# Adding Colored Events to the Calendar

Tags: coldfusion, fullcalendar

I have the following working Calendar page (lqCalendar.cfm) that places events from MySQL to the calendar.

```
<html>
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" />
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        editable: true,
        events: "getLeaveRequests.cfc?method=getMyData",
        eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
            alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                '(should probably update your database)');
        }           
    });

});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id='calendar'>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is my working CFC (getLeaveRequests.cfc) which queries the data:

```
    <!--- Don't forget to VAR scope all local variables. --->
    <cfset var getEvents = "">
    <cfset var row = "">
    <cfset var result = "">

    <cfquery name="getEvents" datasource="care">
        SELECT lqID AS id, 
            lqStartDate AS myStart, 
            lqEndDate AS myEnd, 
            CONCAT(lqUser, " (",lqTotalHours,") ",    (COALESCE(lqDescription,'')),"") AS title
        FROM tblleaverequest
    </cfquery>

    <cfset result = []>
    <cfloop query="getEvents">
        <!--- start new structure. must use array notation to preserve case  of structure keys--->
        <cfset row = {}>
        <cfset eventurl ="leave_request_a01z.cfm?id=" & "id">
        <cfset row["id"] = id>
        <cfset row["title"] = title>
        <cfset row["start"] = myStart>
        <cfset row["end"] = myEnd>

        <!--- append to results --->
        <cfset arrayAppend(result, row)>
    </cfloop>

    <!--- convert to json --->
    <cfreturn serializeJSON(result)>

   <!---
    <cfreturn getEvents>
    --->
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

What is the best way to "color" the calendar items based on the value of "lqUser"?
- The colors can be dynamically assigned, or if needed, I can add a color field to the User table for each user, but how do I assign it to the FullCalendar?

Here is my updated CFC trying to get colors to work: (using code from "dwayne anderson" post on Raymond Camden site)
- I added a field to my User table called "category_id", then assigned values 1 thru 9 for colors.
The page gives me no errors, just a blank calendar?

```
<!--- Component to get all of the Leave Request Dates and place on FullCalendar page--->
<cfcomponent>
<cfsetting showDebugOutput='No'>
<cffunction name="getMyData" output="false" access="remote" returntype="any" returnformat="JSON">
        <cfargument name="filter" type="string" required="no" default="">

<cfquery name="getallevents" datasource="care">
SELECT lqID AS id, 
                lqStartDate AS event_start_datetime, 
                lqEndDate AS event_end_datetime, 
                IF(category_id IS NULL, '1', category_id) AS color_id,
                CONCAT(lqUser, " (",lqTotalHours,") ", (COALESCE(lqDescription,'')),"") AS title
FROM      tblusers RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblleaverequest ON tblusers.username = tblleaverequest.lqUser
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="getallcolors" dbtype="query">
Select distinct color_id
from getallevents
</cfquery>

<cfset colorlist="red,green,blue,yellow,black,brown,aqua,orange,darkred">
<cfset colorpos=1>
<cfset colors = []>

<cfloop query = "getallcolors"> 
<cfset thecolor='#listgetat(colorlist,colorpos)#'>
<cfif colorpos eq listlen(colorlist)>
<cfset colorpos=0>
</cfif>
<cfset colorpos=colorpos+1> 
<cfset colors[#color_id#] = thecolor>
</cfloop>

<cfset url.returnformat="json">
<cfset results = []>
<cfloop query = "getallevents"> 
<cfset eventurl ="eventdetails.cfm?id=" & "id">
<cfset eventcolor   ="#colors[color_id]#">
<cfset s = structnew()>
<cfset s["id"] = id>
<cfset s["title"] = title>
<cfset s["start"] = getEpochTime(event_start_datetime)>
<cfset s["end"] = getEpochTime(event_end_datetime)>
<cfset s["url"] = eventurl>
<cfset s["color"] = eventcolor>
<cfset s["allDay"] = false> 
<cfset arrayappend(results, s)>
</cfloop>

<cfreturn results>
</cffunction>

<cffunction access="private" name="getEpochTime" returntype="date">
<cfargument name="thedatetime" type="date"/>
<cfif (ArrayLen(Arguments) is 0)>
<cfset thedatetime = Now() />
<cfelseif IsDate(Arguments[1])>
<cfset thedatetime=Arguments[1] />
<cfelse>
return NULL;
</cfif>
<cfreturn DateDiff("s", DateConvert("utc2Local", "January 1 1970 00:00"), thedatetime) />
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to "color" the calendar items based on the value of "lqUser"?
>   You have two options if I am understanding this correctly.

1. You could set the color for the user in the query itself so its easier to manage at query level via case statments or any other logic
2. You could do div with classes for specific user or type of user.

HTH.

Comment: ah, I'm trying your option #1, see my updated CFC above. I updated the CFC trying to get colors to work: (using code from "dwayne anderson" post on Raymond Camden site), but it's now just giving me a blank calendar? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! Here is the final & working CFC that includes coloring the calendar events. Thanks for the help.

```
<!--- Component to get all of the Leave Request Dates and place on FullCalendar page--->
<cfcomponent>
    <cfsetting showDebugOutput='No'>

    <cffunction name="getMyData" output="false" access="remote" returntype="any" returnformat="JSON">
        <cfargument name="filter" type="string" required="no" default="">

        <!--- Don't forget to VAR scope all local variables. --->
        <cfset var getEvents = "">
        <cfset var row = "">
        <cfset var result = "">
        <cfset var getallcolors = "">

        <!--- Query the Leave Requests table and get data for all employees --->
        <cfquery name="getEvents" datasource="care">
         SELECT lqID AS id, 
                lqStartDate AS myStart, 
                lqEndDate AS myEnd, 
                IF(category_id IS NULL, "", category_id) AS color_id,
                CONCAT(lqUser, " (",lqTotalHours,") ", (COALESCE(lqDescription,'')),"") AS title
         FROM      tblusers RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblleaverequest ON tblusers.username = tblleaverequest.lqUser
        </cfquery>

        <!--- Do a Query of Queries to get all of the users color values --->
        <cfquery name="getallcolors" dbtype="query">
         Select distinct color_id
         FROM getEvents
        </cfquery>

        <cfset result = []>
        <!--- Assign colors to be used by the FullCalendar variable --->
        <cfset colorlist="red,green,blue,black,gray,brown,orange,darkred,darkgreen,darkblue,darkgrey,purple,darkorange,">
        <cfset colorpos=1>
        <cfset colors = []>

        <cfloop query = "getallcolors"> 
         <cfset thecolor='#listgetat(colorlist,colorpos)#'>
         <cfif colorpos eq listlen(colorlist)>
         <cfset colorpos=0>
         </cfif>
         <cfset colorpos=colorpos+1>    
         <cfset colors[#color_id#] = thecolor>
        </cfloop>




        <cfloop query="getEvents">
            <!--- start new structure. must use array notation to preserve case of structure keys--->
            <cfset row = {}>
            <cfset eventcolor ="#colors[color_id]#">
            <cfset eventurl ="leave_request_a01z.cfm?id=" & "id">
            <cfset row["id"] = id>
            <cfset row["title"] = title>
            <cfset row["start"] = myStart>
            <cfset row["end"] = myEnd>
            <cfset row["color"] = eventcolor>
            <!--- append to results --->
            <cfset arrayAppend(result, row)>
        </cfloop>

        <!--- convert to json --->
        <cfreturn serializeJSON(result)>

       <!---
        <cfreturn getEvents>
        --->
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```